# Pseudo code for this algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am new to `LaTeX` ... I have searched many examples of `algo` pseudocode for this type of code.I don't know which package to use to write this algorithm.

Please help me with the code.

[image]

Comment: Hello you can use The Listings Package : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings

Comment: @flav: The `listings` package might work, but there are better ones for this particular task: `algorithmic`, `algorithm2e` etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What kind of documentclass do you prefer?

Comment: @flav  can u please give me the link of code examples

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example with algorithm2e.[You can find more about it in the documentation in CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\caption{An Algorithm}
\label{alg:algo1}

\KwIn{Some input}
\KwOut{Some Output}

$F_{i}\leftarrow0$\;
Do something\;
\For {$i=1$ \thinspace to 100}{
    Do something one thing\;
    $F_{i}\leftarrow F_{i} + 1$\;
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: algo1]

Answer (score 0):

Here a very simple example with perl :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=perl, numbers=left}
\begin{lstlisting}
#!/usr/bin/perl
## flav
## 2003-08-05
##

sub usage
{
    my  $num_arg;

    $num_arg = $#ARGV;
    if ($num_arg)
    {
    print "Usage: $0 name_of_program\n";
    exit(-1);
    }   
}

sub rl
{
    my  $exe;

    usage();
    $exe = $ARGV[0];
    while (1)
    {
    if (fork())
    {
        wait();
    }
    else
    {
        sleep 600;
        system("date");
        exec($exe);
    }
    }
}

rl();

\end{lstlisting}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

You will find all the doc : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings

But  [Chritan Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) is right there are some better package for your specific matter